# Can you deal non-lethal sneak attack damage with natural weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, sneak-attack, natural-weapon

Can you deal non-lethal sneak attack damage with natural weapons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, unless your natural weapon normally deals nonlethal damage.

> With a sap (blackjack) or an unarmed strike, a rogue can make a sneak attack that deals nonlethal damage instead of lethal damage. **She cannot use a weapon that deals lethal damage to deal nonlethal damage in a sneak attack, not even with the usual -4 penalty.**

(emphasis mine)

Natural weapon is not an unarmed strike and deals lethal damage (If it is not some special natural weapon that normally deals nonlethal damage).

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  But it needs a feat.

Subduing Strike, a feat from the Book of Exalted Deeds (pg 46) allows you to do nonlethal damage with any melee weapon, including Sneak Attack.

See [Do natural attacks count as melee weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45487/do-natural-attacks-count-as-melee-weapons) for further details on natural weapons as melee weapon.

If you are a Monk, the Monk's Unarmed Strike class feature, allows for nonlethal damage explicitly at no penalty, so you can use Sneak Attack freely.

Comment: Please include this as something other then an answer, since the question has already been answered. Thanks for the tip on the feat btw! :)

Comment: @Simon No, this is the right place for Scrollreader's post. A question can have new answers even if it already has an accepted answer. (Where else could it go, anyway?)